# OneSignal dont send notification to specific device

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, onesignal

I want send notification to specific user, i can get the id but when i try to send a notification to these id doesn't work.
In android does not send either success or error notification, and ios send a "index.html null" notification.

The notifications arrive the same device from where I send them, none arrives at the device where I want to send them.

this is app.component.js:

```
let notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        let alert =alertCtrl.create({
          title: jsonData.notification.payload.title,
          subTitle: jsonData.notification.payload.body,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      };

      window["plugins"].OneSignal
        .startInit("05d411f4-45da-4101-92a5-4a60e5c9fd03", "49543248748")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit(); 
    });
```

and with this code i send de notification

```
window['plugins'].OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
        let notificationObj = { contents: {"en": "Han hecho un nuevo pedido"},
                                heading: { "en": "Domi-Trustik" },
                                include_player_ids: [this.idadmin]
                          };
    window['plugins'].OneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj,
    function(successResponse) {

      console.log("Notification Post Success:", successResponse);
      alert("enviado:" + JSON.stringify(successResponse));
    },
    function (failedResponse) {
      console.log("Notification Post Failed: ", failedResponse);
      alert("error" + JSON.stringify(failedResponse));
    }
    );
   });
```

Is in Ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

Its de same error of my other onesignal question, the plugin its no work fine for some functions so its better use native ionic version:

```
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';

constructor(public one: OneSignal)

this.one.getIds().then((ids) => {

                let notificationObj = {
                                        include_player_ids: [this.idadmin],
                                        contents: {en: "Han hecho un nuevo pedido"}};

                      window['plugins'].OneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj,
                      function(successResponse) {

                      console.log("Notification Post Success:", successResponse);
                      alert("enviado:" + JSON.stringify(successResponse));
                      },
                      function (failedResponse) {
                      console.log("Notification Post Failed: ", failedResponse);
                      alert("error" + JSON.stringify(failedResponse));
                      }
                      );

            });
```